# Realm queries and filters

Tags: swift, realm

For illustration purposes, lets say I have classes like this.

```
Class Person {
     dynamic var id = 0
     dynamic var name = ""
     let dogList = List<Dog>()
}

Class Dog {
    dynamic var id = 0
    dynamic var name = ""
}
```

If in Realm database I have 1 person name John with 10 dogs. However I just want to retrieve John's info and one of his dogs called "Fluff" for json serializing. So it would be like:

```
{
    "PersonList" : [{
        "id" : 1
        "name" : "John"
        "DogList" : [{
            "id" = 0
            "name" = "Fluff"
        }]
    }]
}
```

If it was for the dog objects only, I'll be able to do something like this.

```
let dogsList = realm.objects(Dog).filter({ $0.name == "Fluff" })
```

But I also need the information from the Person object.

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? It appears you are actually trying to retrieve TWO objects 1) John    and   2) the dog, Fluff. Would a simple solution be to retrieve John and then his dog, Fluff, from that object?

Comment: Yes, Im trying to retrieve both John and his dog. So I guess that I have to retrieve John, then his dog, cause I was wondering if there was a way for me to filter the dogs to only contain Fluff.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for [inverse relationship](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#inverse-relationships)

```
class Dog: Object {
    dynamic var name = ""
    dynamic var age = 0
    let owners = LinkingObjects(fromType: Person.self, property: "dogList")
}
```

Comment: Nope. I know about inverse relationship. I just need a way to query Person object to have one dog.